# How to call different event selecting and clicking on jstree (vakata)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

In jstree I have two function for select and deselect, I want it an event for click.

```
$(function () {
    $('#tree_folder').on('deselect_node.jstree Event', function (e, data) {
        var item_id = data.node.id;

        setPermission(item_id, $role, 1);
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#tree_folder').on('select_node.jstree Event', function (e, data) {
        var item_id = data.node.id;

        setPermission(item_id, $role, 0);
    });
});
```

I use these two event for select and deselect but these are working even clicking a node. When I click a node (not a checkbox) it calls select or deselect event and add or remove the check to node.
How can I write a function for click event on jstree without selecting or deselecting?

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler you can check to see whether or not the element clicked was your checkbox.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3bsqqkm/) has an even listener on a big div, but only executes functionality if the user clicked on a li within the div and not the div itself.

In your case, it sounds like you want to examine e to see if it is the checkbox and only then call your setPermission method, otherwise do nothing.

**JavaScript**

```
function handler(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is("li")) {
        target.children().toggle();
    } else {
        //alert('target is not li');
    }
}
$("div").click(handler).find("ul ul").hide();
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:100px;background-color:wheat;">
    <ul>
        <li>item 1
            <ul>
                <li>sub item 1-a</li>
                <li>sub item 1-b</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>item 2
            <ul>
                <li>sub item 2-a</li>
                <li>sub item 2-b</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```